# trouble constructing tables through sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am trying to create tables in SqlAlchemy based on Models I created using psycopg2 to connect to PostGres. For some reason when I call Base.metadata.create_all(engine) it throws me the error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_run_visitor'. I've tried looking for this error, but don't really understand what it means. I don't know if I need to have a different version of Python or what. I am using Python 3.8 and SqlAlchemy version 1.3.19. Here is the code associated with what I'm trying to do. If this is annoying to look through you can look at my gitHub repo here https://github.com/u1209855/baseball. Thanks so much in advance! It's going to have more unneeded info in the repo than what's here, I think this all you need in order to answer the question. EDIT on this is I did echo = True and it appears that it does connect to the psql database, so I'm not sure why it can't create those tables...ANOTHER EDIT, tried downloading past versions of sqlalchemy but had no luck.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, INTEGER, NVARCHAR, TIMESTAMP, ForeignKey, DECIMAL, UniqueConstraint, JSON, \
FLOAT, VARCHAR, DATE
from database import Base


class Master(Base):
   __tablename__ = "master"
   __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
   playerID = Column(VARCHAR(10), primary_key=True)
   birthYear = Column(VARCHAR(4))
   birthDay = Column(INTEGER)
   birthCountry = Column(VARCHAR(15))
   birthState = Column(VARCHAR(30))
   deathYear = Column(VARCHAR(4))
   deathMonth = Column(INTEGER)
   deathDay = Column(INTEGER)
   deathCountry = Column(VARCHAR(15))
   deathState = Column(VARCHAR(30))
   deathCity = Column(VARCHAR(30))
   nameFirst = Column(VARCHAR(20))
   nameLast = Column(VARCHAR(20))
   nameGiven = Column(VARCHAR(60))
   weight = Column(INTEGER)
   height = Column(INTEGER)
   bats = Column(VARCHAR(1))
   debut = Column(DATE)
   finalGame = Column(DATE)
   retroID = Column(VARCHAR(10))
   bbrefID = Column(VARCHAR(10))


def create_models(engine):
   # print("dropping tables")
   # Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
   print("creating tables")
   Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Here is my database.py

```
    import sqlalchemy
    import os
    import models as m
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    Base = declarative_base()


  def sqlalchemy_connect():
     conn_str = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@localhost:5432/{database}'.\
     format(user="postgres",
           password="some_password",
           database='baseball')
     engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_str
                                  ,use_batch_mode=True
                                  ,server_side_cursors=True)
     Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(autoflush=False)
     Session.configure(bind=engine)
     session = Session()
     return engine, session


def sqlalchemy_session():
   engine = sqlalchemy_connect()
   session = sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session(sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker())
   session.configure(bind=engine, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False)
   return engine, session


def main():
   engine = sqlalchemy_connect()
   m.create_models(engine)
```

Here is my main that I run.

```
    import models as m
    import database as db

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       engine, session = db.sqlalchemy_session()
       m.create_models(engine)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my function sqlalchemy_connect() just needed to return engine, not session and it seemed to do the trick.